# Domain with SSL showing "Not Secure" on only one Google account

Tags: http, ssl, caching, dns

So I switched the DNS settings for my site a couple weeks ago, and ever since, it's been showing as "Secure" for one of my Google accounts, but "Not Secure" for my other Google account.

Many of my friends who have visited the site before are seeing this same "Not Secure" notice, and it advises the user to not fill in credit card details. But anyone who is visiting the site for the first time is seeing "Secure". This is obviously not a good look.

At first, I thought it was merely a propagation issue, but after 2 weeks of the same issue, it's become apparent that it has to be something to do with the cache, since it's only showing for people who have been to the site before. I'd really like to understand what's going on here and how I can fix it.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean with the site showing differently *for different google accounts*. What has the display of the site to do with the account? Apart from that the problem can not be reproduced based on the current amount of information - one would at least need to know the domain name. If you don't want to publish it analyze your site with [SSLLabs](https://ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and fix your site until you got at least a rating of A on all possible IP addresses your site might have. Then your problem might have been solved while doing this also.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for the info and link to SSLLabs. It got all A's. "What has the display of the site to do with the account?" I guess this is the core of my question, really. I viewed the site with one of my Google accounts when it was insecure. And when I view the site with that account, it still shows as insecure. However, if I view it as my other Google account, it shows "Secure". And pretty much everyone who had viewed the site before it was secure, is having the same issue. But all new users who first viewed it after it was secured, are not having this issue. Does that make sense?

Comment: No, it does not make sense. You can view a site with a browser, but your cannot view a site *"with that account"*. Do you mean that display of the site changes depending on with which account you are logged into Google when using the browser? I think you really need to provide a way for others to reproduce your issue, i.e. provide the actual URL where the problem happens.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich https://imgur.com/a/E6xMSWT here's a comparison between the two different google accounts on Chrome. Taken a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 1):

This question has not really anything to do with different Google accounts but more with different working environments - which might be associated with different accounts but don't really need to be. My guess is that you've been changing the configuration of your website: where you've once had a 301 redirect from `http://` to `https://` you've removed it later.

In the environment where you've visited the site at the time the redirect was active it got the 301 redirect and thus moved from `http://` to `https://`. Since 301 is a permanent redirect it cached  this information, i.e. whenever you enter `http://your-domain` it will directly go to `https://your-domain` without checking with the server first.

In the other environments the browser does not know that there was once a 301 redirect since it never saw it and since it is no longer there. Thus the browser will stay on the `http://` site since this is what the browser does by default. If you would clear all caches in the environment where you get the `https://` it should no longer remember the cached 301 and behave similar to the other environments, i.e. staying with `http://` and not automatically going to `https://`.

Note that instead of a 301 redirect you might have also installed a HSTS header and removed it later. This would have the same effect.

To fix the problem and make all visitors go to the secured `https://` version of your site you need to install the 301 redirect and/or the HSTS header again - and keep it installed this time.

Comment: Interesting. I don't think I have any 301 redirects, but I might. My DNS provider points directly to a heroku custom domain name with CNAME records. Would that be the issue, since it's not pointing directly to an IP? It's a Rails app that is forcing SSL on an application level. Perhaps that functions as a redirect? I've tried clearing my cache several times to no avail. Any way I can fix this for previous users who are experiencing the same thing?

Comment: *"It's a Rails app that is forcing SSL on an application level. Perhaps that functions as a redirect? "* - this might be. Such a redirect or setting HSTS header can be done from the application too.  But the problem is that contrary to your claim currently nothing is forcing SSL. If your intention is that this was done by the rails application it probably worked at some time (and was thus cached in some environments) but there might be recently introduced  bug in your application which results in no longer forcing SSL.

Comment: *"I've tried clearing my cache several times to no avail."* - it is not clear what you exactly did here and in which environment. Clearing the cache will not help to force SSL, it will only help to no longer force SSL when done correctly and in the right environment.